# Missing some custom fields on Content Query

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part

I need to display my custom list rows using a custom XSLT, so I have configured a CQWP to display these rows from this specific list. Although, even the Order by dropdown list displaying all list fields (even custom fields), some of them are not recognized within the XSLT code. Why some custom fields are display and some of them not?

The type of the list fields that are not being displayed is text (single or multiline).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To display additional fields in [Content Query web part (CQWP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms492595.aspx) specify them in property [CommonViewFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.commonviewfields.aspx).

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.commonviewfields.aspx):

> CommonViewFields are additional fields that you can request when
>   retrieving data. You can format the fields as either "internalName" or
>   "Guid", separated by semicolons. You can specify the field types by
>   placing a comma after the internal name or the GUID

### Usage

In order to display additional fields:

```
Internal Name: JobTitle Type:Text
Internal Name: JobDescription Type: Note
```

specify CommonViewFields property

```
<property name="CommonViewFields" type="string">JobTitle,Text;JobDescription,Note</property>
```

After that they could be used in XSLT, like that:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@JobTitle" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I just don't understand why some custom fields are displayed without any customization.

Comment: You might have specified those fields in the web part properties. Check Presentation->Title and Description text fields